# Android, Thread, Cannot unregister SensorEventListener

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I seem to be having the same problem as this gentleman:
[SensorEventListener doesn't get unregistered with unregisterListener() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919577/sensoreventlistener-doesnt-get-unregistered-with-unregisterlistener-method)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            ...
            loopThread();
}

private void loopThread() {
            boolean found = kill;
            System.out.println("Looping until Found!");
            locationThread = new Thread(){
                    private float myacc;

                    @Override
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            while (found == false && !kill){
                                    System.out.println("Another Loop!");
                                    getMyLoc();
                                    found = isFound(mylat,mylng,target_lat,target_lng,radius);
                                    try {
                                            synchronized(locationThread){
                                                    locationThread.wait(100);
                                            }

                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mAccelerometer);
                            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mGravitometer);
                            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener);
                            locationThread.interrupt();
                    }
}

@Override
    public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mAccelerometer);
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mGravitometer);
            locationThread.interrupt();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            senslistener = new mySensorEventListener();
            mSensorManager.registerListener(senslistener, mAccelerometer,     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(senslistener, mGravitometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            if (true)
                    loopThread();
    }

private void registerSensors() {
            mSensorManager =     (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            List<Sensor> mySensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
            if(mySensors.size() > 0){
                    mAccelerometer =     mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                    mGravitometer =     mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

                    mSensorManager.registerListener(senslistener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(senslistener, mGravitometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Getting your location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No ORIENTATION Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, MFLMain.class);
                    if (locationThread != null)
                            if(locationThread.isAlive()){

                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mAccelerometer);
                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener, mGravitometer);
                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(senslistener);
                    locationThread.interrupt();
                            }
                    locator.stopListener();
                    kill = true;
                    System.out.println("Kill the app "+kill);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return false;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

When I hit back to hide the application and kill the activity, I still get the system.out in logcat.  The thead quits, as evidenced by the lack of system.out there.  I am very confused and I don't think scope is the issue as the sensormanager is being instantiated through an init method and nowhere else .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a long shot but the only thing I can see different from examples that have worked and yours ( without seeing additional code ) would be to implement the SensorEventListener and pass this into the register and unregister events instead of your custom SensorEventListener.

see this stackoverflow of someone trying it your way by using the new operator to instantiate the listener and the answer that seemed to work for him.

[How to convert a program that uses SensorListener to SensorEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394192/how-to-convert-a-program-that-uses-sensorlistener-to-sensoreventlistener)

```
public class MySensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        ...
        loopThread();
}

  private void loopThread() {
        boolean found = kill;
        System.out.println("Looping until Found!");
        locationThread = new Thread(){
                private float myacc;

                @Override
                @Override
                public void run() {

                        while (found == false && !kill){
                                System.out.println("Another Loop!");
                                getMyLoc();
                                found = isFound(mylat,mylng,target_lat,target_lng,radius);
                                try {
                                        synchronized(locationThread){
                                                locationThread.wait(100);
                                        }

                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mGravitometer);
                        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                        locationThread.interrupt();
                }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mGravitometer);
        locationThread.interrupt();
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        registerSensors();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGravitometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        if (true)
                loopThread();
}

private void registerSensors() {
        mSensorManager =     (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List<Sensor> mySensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
        if(mySensors.size() > 0){
                mAccelerometer =     mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                mGravitometer =     mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

                mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGravitometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Getting your location...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "No ORIENTATION Sensor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}


 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MFLMain.class);
                if (locationThread != null)
                        if(locationThread.isAlive()){

                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mGravitometer);
                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                locationThread.interrupt();
                        }
                locator.stopListener();
                kill = true;
                System.out.println("Kill the app "+kill);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```